# eZ Publish 5.X "Store draft" button is hidden

Tags: ezpublish

**Hi**, I have some problem with eZPublish 5.x, I want to enable "Store draft" button on editing articles, now is enabled "Store draft and exit" button but i want without a "Exit".I look in code and on load page "Store draft" button have attribute "hidden" and "display:none", where i can enable or disable this buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have ezautosave enabled?

If yes then you have a setting in ezautosave.ini that you can override in your own settings folder

```
[AutosaveSettings]
# whether to hide the Store draft button
HideStoreDraftButton=disabled
```

Comment: your suggestion help me ,  Thank you very much! problem is solved.